# Install a specific Node.js version (overriding any other available on a shared host system)

Tags: node.js

I’m running a Node.js based FOSS Kanban board (WeKan) on a shared host system (`Linux 3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64`), which relies on `Node.js 14.21.3`. The hoster is ending support for `Node.js 14.21.3`. Unfortunately the devs of the software are not ready to support a newer `Node.js` for quite a while. My question is how to override any given Node.js version in favour of 14.21.3. I have tried `nvm` or `n`, but I don’t have privileges for versions unsupported by the hoster.

Hosting support said they allow installing my own Node.js, but don't give instructions as they don’t want users to run old and insecure software. This is as far as they would support me:

```
$ VERSION="14.21.3"
$ SOURCE="https://nodejs.org/download/release/v${VERSION}/node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz"
$ DEST="${HOME}/opt/node${VERSION}"

$ mkdir --parents "${DEST}"
$ wget "${SOURCE}"
$ tar zxvf "node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz"
$ mv "node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64/"* "${DEST}/"
$ rm -rf "node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64" "node-v${VERSION}-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

Question:
Now I need to have this version at `/home/me/opt/node14.21.3/bin/node` override persistently whatever `Node.js` version the hoster provides. A matching version of `npm` is needed to install future versions of that Kanban board (WeKan). Please help me getting there, thank you!

This is my environment:

```
$ id
uid=1324(me) gid=1324(me) Gruppen=1324(me) Kontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

$ sudo -l
Passende Defaults-Einträge für me auf server:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR
    USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

umask
$ umask
0002

$ whoami
me
```